# python program 2 tuples as arguments and returns a sorted tuple containing elements that are found in both tuples

Tags: python, tuples

My code :

```
def commonElements(t1 ,t2):
    t1 = sorted(t1)
    t2 = sorted(t2)
    t3 = set([])
    for i in t1:
        for j in t2:
            if i == j:
               t3.add(i)
        return t3
print commonElements((1, 2, 3), (2, 5, 1))
```

For the above code am getting output as:

```
set([1, 2])
```

Expected should be:

```
  (1, 2)
```

common elements are printing in the form of set. How to  convert set to tuple??

Comment: there are only two tuples or more.?

Comment: `var = ((1, 2, 3), (2, 5, 1))`
`tuple(set(var[0]).intersection(var[1]))`

Answer (score 5):

I would convert the two parameters to Python's `set` type, and then use the set intersection operator between the two sets. After that, you can cast the result to a tuple as you wanted.

```
def commonElements(t1 ,t2):
    return tuple(set(t1) & set(t2))
```

Per your example:

```
>>> commonElements((1, 2, 3), (2, 5, 1))
(1, 2)
```

Comment: Please avoid posting answers that are only code, when possible. Accompany your code with an explanation for what it's doing and how it works.

Comment: @ZachGates Done boss ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you need to return sorted tuple. I would add to @gsi-frank's answer `sorted()` method.

```
def commonElements(t1, t2):
    return tuple(sorted(set(t1) & set(t2)))
```